# Something analogous to a symlink in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, record

Would it be possible to store a "link" to another record inside a record? For example:

```
table USERS
id    name    link
-------------------------------------------------------
1     user1   [link to record with id=4 in table info]
```

So, in PHP, I could do something like this:

```
// connect to the database etc....
$query          = "select * from users where id=1";
$result         = mysql_query($query);
$another_result = mysql_result($result, 0, 'link');
```

So that `$another_result` stores the result of another query, in the same raw format as if it was called using `mysql_query()`.

Is this possible?

Comment: One might also call it SQL: $another_result = mysql_result(mysql_query($result[0]['link']));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query          = "select info.* from info 
                   inner join users on users.link = info.id 
                   where users.id=1";
$result         = mysql_query($query);
```

Using `JOIN` is a fundamental part of SQL, like using `for` loops in PHP.

Read [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) by fearless leader.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean a key that point to a another key in another table, so for example you can have something like this :

```
table USERS
id    name    info_id
-------------------------------------------------------
1     user1   4

table INFO
id    info    
--------------
4     someinfo
```

With a JOIN you can get for example a resultset with the "linked" fields :

```
SELECT u.name AS name, i.info AS info
FROM USERS u
JOIN INFO i ON u.info_id = i.id
```

Answer (score 1):

MySql is a so called relational database and having relations (links) between tables is one of the key concepts. In your specific case the "link" you want is called a Foreign Key. You might want to have [a read here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/performance/sql-by-design-the-foreign-key) (there are many more articles around if you have a look on google).

You can retrieve linked records via a [JOIN operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) as the other answerers have already told you.